# rails: Login not working with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I want to login on my server with json. The create method works with my custom view (new.html.erb), but not with json.
I am using the gem devise.

sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  def new
    #empty because no underlying model
  end


  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])

    respond_to do |format|
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password]) #because user has_secure_password
        session[:user_id] = user.id

        format.html { redirect_to images_path, notice: "Login successful!" }
        format.json { render :json => {:success => true,
                      :info => "Logged in" } }
      else
        format.html { flash.now.alert = "Wrong email or password"
                    render "new" }
        format.json { render :json => {:success => false, :info => "Wrong email or password" } }
      end
    end
  end



  def destroy

    session[:user_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookmarks_path, notice: "Logout successful!" }
      format.json { render :json => {:success => true,
                      :info => "Logged out",
                      :data => { } } }
    end

  end


end
```

user.rb

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :encrypted_password

      has_secure_password

      validates :email, format: /^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, uniqueness: true

end
```

routes.rb:

```
#user
  resources :users , only: [:new, :create]

  #session
  get "login" => "sessions#new", as: "login"
  post "sessions" => "sessions#create", as: "sessions"
  delete "logout" => "sessions#destroy", as: "logout"
```

rake routes:

```
users POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
  new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
     login GET    /login(.:format)           sessions#new
  sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)        sessions#create
    logout DELETE /logout(.:format)          sessions#destroy
```

I use the Chrome extension Simple REST Client to test the server via HTTP POST with my json data (the user already exists in the database and login from the new.html.erb view works):

```
url:           http://localhost:3000/sessions
method:        POST
Content-Type:  application/json
               Accept: application/json
Data:          {"user":{ "email":"test@test.at","password":"asdf" }}
```

As response, I get status 200 OK, but:

```
{"success":false,"info":"Wrong email or password"}
```

although email and password are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the email and the password in the root of your json object or access them like `params[:user][:email]`.